# DOM and Javascript Comparison

Tags: javascript

I want to compare the state of objects and variables in Javascript as well as the DOM between two different times.  Basically I want to very easily determine what things are set at and why a piece of code is reacting particular way without spending a lot of time stepping through code.

Comment: What is the purpose what's happening, a bug?

Comment: This answer may give you some place to start, depending on what you are trying to do:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Basically I have a condition that is operating operating properly when a set of functions are called first.  When I try to reset the state to do it again, it doesn't work.  I want to determine what about the entire DOM is different and start comparing the differences.